# Error reading from PROGMEM

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I was trying to run a code from this https://circuits4you.com/2018/03/10/esp8266-jquery-and-ajax-web-server/

I am pasting it here.

```
/*
 * ESP8266 NodeMCU jQuery CDN Demo
 * 
 * https://circuits4you.com
 */
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

//ESP Web Server Library to host a web page
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------
//Our HTML webpage contents in program memory
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
      });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
  <p>Click me away!</p>
  <p>Click me too!</p>
  <br><hr>
  <a href="https://circuits4you.com">circuits4you.com</a>  
  </body>
  </html>
)=====";
//---------------------------------------------------------------

//On board LED Connected to GPIO2
#define LED 2  

//SSID and Password of your WiFi router
const char* ssid = "circuits4you.com";
const char* password = "yourWiFipassword";

//Declare a global object variable from the ESP8266WebServer class.
ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80

//===============================================================
// This routine is executed when you open its IP in browser
//===============================================================
void handleRoot() {
 Serial.println("You called root page");
 String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}
//==============================================================
//                  SETUP
//==============================================================
void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     //Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  //Onboard LED port Direction output
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT); 

  //Power on LED state off
  digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //WiFi mode station (connect to wifi router only
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP
 
  server.on("/", handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location. This is display page

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
//==============================================================
//                     LOOP
//==============================================================
void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();          //Handle client requests
}
```

When I deploy this to my nodemcu esp-12e, I a m getting below error

I used the exception decoder

```
Exception 3: LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store
PC: 0x4000bf64
EXCVADDR: 0x4023d581
```

From the decoder it says the offending line is this one

```
void handleRoot() {
 Serial.println("You called root page");
 String s = MAIN_page; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Error on this line
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); 
}
```

It looks like it cannot read from the variable in PROGMEM..

I replaced that line with this code and converting it into a string and the error was gone.

```
String MAIN_page = R"=====(
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
      });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
  <p>Click me away!</p>
  <p>Click me too!</p>
  <br><hr>
  <a href="https://circuits4you.com">circuits4you.com</a>  
  </body>
  </html>
)=====";
```

Is there something wrong in the code that I am following on how it reads the variable from the PROGMEM flash memory?

Comment: `server.send_P(200, "text/html", MAIN_page);`

Comment: [In the ESP32, anything declared as const will end up in the rodata segment, which then will go into flash and is read directly from that.](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=4780). Don't know about the ESP8266.

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html PS why the UNO tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a PROGMEM string directly to a String object. Besides, the whole concept makes no sense, since String objects store their data in RAM regardless.

If you want to use PROGMEM you need to use `const char *` not `String`.

Comment: `String s = (const __FlashStringHelper*) MAIN_page;` would work and does use RAM only temporary. it could be useful to replace some parts of the string. But the whole approach by OP to this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I just followed everything from that link.. I am just not sure how they are able to make it work at their end though.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of using PROGMEM is to save the RAM for other uses.  If you have a huge string that would overflow your RAM then PROGMEM is essential.  However, if the string isn't too large and the program works fine, then just use String instead of PROGMEM.